# bridged network not working VMware player

Tags: vmware-player

I am using VMware-player-7.0.0-2305329, when I configure bridged network configuration to connect to the local-host network, it won't connect and its not even throwing any errors in VMLog as well as in Event Viewer.

Local system configuration:

windows 8

intel core i3-3220 @3.3GHZ processor

8 gb RAM

Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Ver. 8.21.909.2013

Guest System Configuration:

Windows Server 2008 R2

6GB Ram

here's what i have tried to resolve this problem.

1. uninstalled and installed VMWare bridge Protocol in local host network properties.
2. uninstalled vmware player and all the instances from c drive and registry and cleaned using Registry cleaner, restarted the system and installed newer version of VMware Player but still same problem exist.
3. reinstalled VMWare tools in guest OS.

so what you guys think about this problem, is there any solution?

Comment: but there may so many out there as me as a newbee and they are struggling to make it work, if you can move it to related forum because i don't know exactly how to do that, that's why i have posted here.

Comment: I'm yet again obliged to say that Stack Overflow is not a forum. >_>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by following this [LINK](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/487652) .

Actually the problem was with the kaspersky antivirus(Follow the above link) that was installed on my computer, Below is the procedure i followed to make it work.

1. uninstalled the kaspersky Anti-Virus.
2. uninstalled VMware Player.
3. Restarted the system.
4. installed back the VMware Player and make sure that bridge network works correctly before installing Kaspersky back.
5. Reinstalled Kaspersky.

and Voila Everything back in the normal stage and my VM connects to the localhost network.

Hope it helps somebody.